# Highcharts add points but not to all categories

Tags: highcharts, categories

I would like to add points to my highcharts without expecting to fulfill all the categories.
is it possible? any work around?
I've done the same when X data is based on time, but could it be done with other kind of data?
For example one serie could be just Apples and Oranges, but not the other categories. See code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Stacked column chart'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Total fruit consumption'
            },
            stackLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            align: 'right',
            x: -70,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 20,
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColorSolid) || 'white',
            borderColor: '#CCC',
            borderWidth: 1,
            shadow: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.x +'</b><br/>'+
                    this.series.name +': '+ this.y +'<br/>'+
                    'Total: '+ this.point.stackTotal;
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'John',
            data: [[Apples,5], [Oranges, 6]]
        }, {
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [[Grapes,2]]
        }, {
            name: 'Joe',
            data: [[Grapes,2], [Bananas, 4]]
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the indexes into your categories: http://jsfiddle.net/BwyAj/

```
var categories = ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
```

...

```
series: [{
        name: 'John',
        data: [[categories.indexOf('Apples'),5], [categories.indexOf('Oranges'), 6]]
    }, {
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [[categories.indexOf('Grapes'),2]]
    }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [[categories.indexOf('Grapes'),2], [categories.indexOf('Bananas'), 4]]
    }]
```